# Create an API endpoint within Sanity?

Tags: sanity

How can we create an endpoint using Sanity CMS which lets us execute custom server-side code? e.g. `https://my-sanity-cms.com/api/my-endpoint`

Within NextJS we can create `/pages/api/endpoint.js` and we can then access `.com/api/endpoint` via any http clients.

We want to be able to do this as our CMS needs to talk to some 3rd party systems and execute some server-side code, so ideally we can make an endpoint we can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just set that up with NextJS and have it do whatever it needs to do using the Sanity APIs to read/write content inside Sanity and the 3rd party APIs to do whatever they need to do. You can then deploy that with Vercel or similar and use that endpoint from inside the studio.

There is however no way to run custom code inside the Sanity backend service, but lots of companies deploy separate projects in order to integrate data across systems.

Comment: We're not using NextJS, that was just an example of how you set up api routes, and asking how we can do the same in Sanity.

But your second paragraph says that there's no way to add custom endpoints into a sanity project?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).